# jquery addClass not applying - am I overlooking something?

Tags: jquery, addclass

I have a div

```
<div id="FBo"></div>
```

If I hard code in a class

```
<div id="FBo" class="myClass"></div>
```

it displays as it should

If instead I use

```
$('#FBo').addClass('myClass');
```

the styling doesn't apply, although if, in the browser, I Ctrl-A and look at the source code, the div code looks like

```
<div class="myClass" id="FBo" ></div>
```

To check that the jquery is loaded and the div is active, I tried

```
$('#FBo').html('blah');
```

and blah shows up.

Is there something else I need to include to get the styling to apply?

Here's the jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/shaunthomson/dRDGG/

Thanks for your help.

Comment: have you added the css for class??

Comment: ^ exactly what I was going to ask

Comment: add !important for all myClass css

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle?

Comment: which version of jquery you are using

Comment: share jsfiddle of your code which replicate your problem.

Comment: Yes - I've added the css for myClass - hard coding in <div class="myClass" id="FBo" ></div> displays the correct styling. Here's the .css - .fbOO{ width:257px !important; display:block !important; margin:0 auto !important; }. I will set up a jsfiddle.

Comment: Here's the jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/shaunthomson/dRDGG/ -f you hard code in <div class="myClass" id="FBo" ></div>, the styling applies, but otherwise the js has no effect.

Comment: Hold up - it's working on jsfiddle, so I'll keep investigating. FYI - I'm using jQuery v1.8.2

Answer (score 1):

try using this

```
$("#FBo").attr("class","myClass");
```

**Note**:

apply ur script after the dom element is loaded

Answer (score 1):

If you include jQuery in your jsfiddle, it just works as expected :

http://jsfiddle.net/dRDGG/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#FBo').addClass('myClass');
});
```